# Visual C# - Redirect Users to Different windows forms according to their User Role

Tags: c#, authentication, user-roles

I want to create a Login form which redirects the user login to the two different form according to the roles of users. I have two forms 1. UserPanelFrm and 2.FrmUserRole and two user role . 1. Admin and 2.User . I want to redirect Admin to UserPanelFrm and User to form FrmUserRole. I researched for this process but only could found useful resources for ASP.NET.

**tbl_Staff:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Staff](
[StaffID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Phone] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[JoinedDate] [date] NULL,
[Username] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [date] NULL,
[Roles] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Status] [int] NULL
}
```

**tbl_StaffRoles:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_StaffRoles](
[id] [int] NULL,
[RoleDescription] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

**tbl_StaffRoles data:**

```
id RoleDescription
1 Admin
2 User
```

Hi, I am currently using following code for normal login.

**LoginForm btnLogin :**

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int result = uc.Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        if (result == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            UserPanelFrm frm = new UserPanelFrm();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**UserClass.cs Login class:**

```
public int Login(String Username, String Password)
{
    try
    {
        int result = 0;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Staff where Username=@Username and Password=@Password", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        conn.Close();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            result = 1;
        else
            result = 0;

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Please help to modify the code so i can redirect users to windows form according to their roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the Login method to return the datatable instead (assuming you have a column for the role in that query):

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable result = uc.Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();

            string role = result.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString();


            switch (role)
            {
                case "User": 
                    UserPanelFrm frm = new UserPanelFrm();
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                    break;
                case "Admin":
                    //Show a different form
                    FrmUserRole fur = new FrmUserRole();
                    fur.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and...

```
public DataTable Login(String Username, String Password)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Staff where Username=@Username and Password=@Password", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion. It worked. Now I get UserPanelfrm when login with the user having role 'Admin' and get FrmUserPanel when login with 'User' role.

Answer (score 0):

You should check "Roles" in tbl_Staff:

```
 public int Login(String Username, String Password)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Staff where Username=@Username and Password=@Password", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                conn.Close();
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string role = dt.Rows[0]["Roles"].ToString();

                    if (role.Equals("User"))
                    {
                        UserPanelFrm frm = new UserPanelFrm();
                        frm.ShowDialog();
                        this.Close();
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if (role.Equals("Admin"))
                    {
                        FrmUserRole fur = new FrmUserRole();
                        fur.ShowDialog();
                        this.Close();
                        return 1;
                    }
                }

                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int result = uc.Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It helped understanding the logic.